# Adding a custom path to the Path environmental variable - how does javac look for the path?

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

Today I have installed the Java Developer Kit. However, when I simply typed `javac` in my console, it returned an error. Only once I had added the location to my Java `bin` folder to the `Path` environmental variable did it finally start to work properly. However, I am not satisfied with this solution and I would like to know exactly why it worked. 
 

How does the process know that once I type `javac` one of those paths needs to be opened? I have never specified the alias for this path before. Also, does the process iterate through every path present on the environmental variable list until it finds the proper path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a command, the directories in path are searched in the order they appear in the variable until the command you typed is found.

See the first answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them